# What is the best strategy to extract information from a JIRA issue?

Tags: python, jira

I'm developing [FreedomSponsors](http://www.freedomsponsors.org) - a crowdfunding platform for open source projects.

I want to improve the "Sponsor new issue" screen by pre-filling some information, based on the issue's URL.

My first "target" is JIRA. 
Given a URL like https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1050,  What's the best way to extract information like:

- 1. issue key: HHH-1050
- 1. project issue tracker URL: https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH

(ok, the first two are easy)

- 1. issue title: "HQL Unions"
- 1. project title: "Hibernate ORM"

I'm using python

Comment: I'd recommend the REST API over XML, since not all custom fields do a great job of their XML views. If you're using JIRA 5.x then take a look at this tool http://summit.atlassian.com/archives/2012/plugin-dev/jira-rest-client-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use the [XML view](https://hibernate.onjira.com/si/jira.issueviews%3aissue-xml/HHH-1050/HHH-1050.xml), which is probably (a) more stable than the HTML rendering and (b) easier to extract information from.

At least for this issue tracker at this location you can get the XML URL

```
https://hibernate.onjira.com/si/jira.issueviews:issue-xml/HHH-1050/HHH-1050.xml
```

from the issue key which is easily obtainable from the original issue URL.

Comment: Whoa, nice! Didn't know about XML view. I'll make some tests and be back with results later..

Comment: Most issue trackers have at least one machine-readable export format, be it XML or CSV. Very handy at times :)

Comment: These are what I tested. All working as expected (thanks!)
That's enough for now... 
+ https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-1050 
+ https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-9216 
+ http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5121
+ http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/EASYMOCK-111
+ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-66

Comment: It may be better to use the JIRA API because the XML view may not be available at all times - i.e. if permission restrictions are applied. Using the API however may imply that user credentials are supplied for the respective issue tracker instance.