# What is the best strategy to extract information from a Github issue?

Tags: python, git, github, issue-tracking

This is the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596405/what-is-the-best-strategy-to-extract-information-from-a-jira-issue), but for Github instead of JIRA

Hi,

I'm developing [FreedomSponsors](http://www.freedomsponsors.org) - a crowdfunding platform for open source projects.

I want to improve the "Sponsor new issue" screen by pre-filling some information, based on the issue's URL.

My next "target" is the Github issue tracking system.

Given a URL like https://github.com/whit537/www.gittip.com/issues/14,  What's the best way to extract information like:

- 1: issue key: 14
- 2: project issue tracker URL: https://github.com/whit537/www.gittip.com/issues
- 3: project title: www.gittip.com

(ok, these are easy, it's all in the URL)
and

- 4: issue title: pay with bitcoin, litecoin

I'm using python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github has an API for issues, thats going to be your best bet.

http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/

Comment: So, this link here has everything I need --> https://api.github.com/repos/whit537/www.gittip.com/issues/14. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I knew Github would never let me down :-)